Rive Animation Website not working on iPhone
I'm sure I am missing something simple... I followed this: https://help.rive.app/runtimes/overview/web-js
It works great until I change the src from ("src: "https://cdn.rive.app/animations/vehicles.riv",") to our servers (src: "https://outofourmindsstudios.com/2024/vehicles.riv",). Then it breaks on iPhone. What am I missing? I still works in Chrome.
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Rive Hello World</title>
  </head>
  
  
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@rive-app/canvas@2.10.3"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/rive-js"></script>
   


    <script>
      const r = new rive.Rive({
        src: "https://outofourmindsstudios.com/2024/vehicles.riv",
        canvas: document.getElementById("canvas"),
        autoplay: true,
        stateMachines: "bumpy",
        onLoad: () => {
          r.resizeDrawingSurfaceToCanvas();
        },
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>`


CORS security is carefully enforced by iPhones. The browser will stop the animation if your server isn't set up to accept requests from the origin (often a separate domain) where your HTML file is hosted.
Try simulating this and inspect the page to check if the console is having CORS issue. Most of the time it happens even when you apply API calls directly.
